# Scanner not storing string as a parsed LocalDateTime correctly

Tags: java, localdatetime

When I am taking in a string variable from the scanner and parsing it to LocalDateTime in the format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm" the Scanner saved the input (i.e 2020-10-12 14:30) without the time. I believe the time is being saved into the next variable. However if I input 2020-10-1214:30 without the space, it saves the the variable correctly.

Below is my constructor where the object is being created and the string is being parsed into the localdatetime object.

```
public computerbooking(String strDAte, String ReturnDate,String computerType,String AssetTag,String StudentId ){
counter++;
this.bookingId  = "Book"+counter;
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
bookingDateAndTime = bookingDateAndTime.parse(strDAte,formatter);
returnDateAndTime = returnDateAndTime.parse(ReturnDate,formatter);
this.computerType = computerType;
this.AssetTag = AssetTag;
this.StudentId = StudentId;

}
```

How do I instruct the scanner not to read the space between the date and time to save it correctly

Comment: It is difficult to answer the question without seeing the code where you use the `Scanner`

Answer (score 1):

1. `LocalDateTime#parse` is a `static` function. Use `LocalDateTime.parse(strDate, formatter)` instead of `bookingDateAndTime.parse(strDAte,formatter)`.
2. Use `Scanner#nextLine` to scan the full line of input. If you are using `Scanner#next`, it will scan only up to `2020-10-12` i.e. it will stop scanning as soon as it will come across a whitespace character after `2020-10-12`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter date and time: ");
        String strDate = scanner.nextLine();

        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm");
        LocalDateTime bookingDateAndTime = LocalDateTime.parse(strDate, formatter);
        System.out.println(bookingDateAndTime);

        // A custom format
        String formatted = bookingDateAndTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd uuuu hh:mm a"));
        System.out.println(formatted);
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter date and time: 2020-10-12 14:30
2020-10-12T14:30
Oct 12 2020 02:30 pm
```